# EPSON TM-T20II printing using RPI2

Tags: linux, printing, raspberry-pi2, cups, lpr

I am attempting to print a text document using a RPi 2 but when I attempt to print the printer just prints out unreadable text eg:-

```
    @EJL 1284.4
    @EJL
    JSGUTENPRINTPMMIɸüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüü
    ÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüü
    üüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖüüüüüÖ etc...
```

This is using the Epson Stylus T20 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (en) driver that came with CUPS.

When I attempt to use the driver from the Epson site I get the following error in CUPS:-

```
     Idle - "File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertotmt" not available: No such file or directory"
```

Has any one else had this issue, or does anybody know where I am able to get an armhf epson printer driver?

Hardware/Software Info:-

```
    PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
    NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
    VERSION_ID="7"
    VERSION="7 (wheezy)"

    Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

    CUPS 1.5.3
    Gutenprint v5.2.9
```

If there is any more info you need please ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Skip CUPS and install this [ESC/POS manipulation library for python.](https://github.com/manpaz/python-escpos/wiki/Raspberry-Pi)
Just tested it with RPI2 & Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the package from plinth666 but the raster wasn't quite proper and the print timing waas quiet long.

I used then a bunch of free code from Epson, a PPD file from another printer and modify them to produce this new package: https://github.com/groolot/epson-tm-t88v-driver

Better rasterization, cash drawer and buzzer, all is operational.

Hope that could help someone like I was: in pain.